# My azure Http Trigger hitting an error because it isn't async. Why is my method not async?

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, .net-core

I'm new to azure and learning how to use HTTP Trigger. I've written a simple function that I'm running locally using azure storage emulator

```
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("PutRecipeInCosmos")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] 
            HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(req.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hey!"));
        }
    }
```

When I hit this function is postman, the azure console returns the following error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core: Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call WriteAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.
```

My method is tagged as async, and includes an await on the return. Why am I seeing this error?

****UPDATE****

I fixed this by returning an returning an OKObjectResult instead of an HttpResonseMesssage. It appears that HttpRequestMessage.Create is a Synchronous IO and cant be handled asynchronously?

```
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("PutRecipeInCosmos")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] 
            HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log)
        {
            return new OkObjectResult("Hey!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think the error is related to the runtime rather than your function itself. Could you please update the function tools? npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools

Comment: Thanks, but this one didnt work for me. I updated and restarted VS. same error on POST.

Comment: is this .net core? which version?

Comment: <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>

Comment: try this one: npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@3

Comment: updated one package, but still throwing the error :(

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

install the following NuGet packages:

Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions package version 1.0.28 or later

then, add a new Startup class with the following content:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
          builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
          {
              options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
          });

          // If using IIS:
          builder.Services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
          {
              options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
          });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like my function to run asynchronously. But, I did try the second option you posted, and I'm still seeing this error

Comment: I can't reproduce it on my machine. Give a try on the first option please.